# What factors contribute to the claim that reality is limited to levels 6 and below?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Sometimes the argument's made that a level 6 (or lower!) human is the best reality can produce.

For example, in this [question's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/42028/8610) Comments...

- a link was provided to this Paizo forums [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r4q4&page=1?Ex-Su-and-Martial-Characters) which discusses, among other things, the skill [Acrobatics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics) being semi-realistic when [jumping](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics#jumping-and-falling).
- [Scott](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/11576/scott) wrote, "A level 5 Monk with the run feat can run the 100 metre sprint in 9.84 seconds, which is enough to get [him] in the Olympics. A level 6 monk can run it in 7.87 seconds, which is superhuman."
- [Bobson](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1905/bobson) wrote, "There's also been analyses done about rangers shooting arrows and researchers doing research" that says as much.

I can imagine *skills* that generate clearly quantifiable effects producing results that lead one to *assuming* that reality *should* end at level 6, but I struggle to see how the same conclusion can be reached if one looks at other parts of either game, for example, combat,<sup>1</sup> hit points,<sup>2</sup> and research.

Outside of a handful of skills that produce results that can be measured and the Speed statistic, what other simulationist *nonmagical* mechanics indicate that reality ends at level 6 or below? **Why should the claim that reality ends at level 6 or below be believed?**

---

1. Especially considering that humanity's combats are simultaneous not sequential and happen second-to-second not in six-second bursts.
2. If using hp as a measure, reality may end at level 1.

Comment: I think the scope of what counts as "reality" and where it breaks needs to be more sharply defined for this question to be usefully answered. "Zombies exist and I can control them with the power of my faith" refutes the premise, as does "Elves," "spells," and "an adventure-based economy."

Comment: @BESW I would say the question applies to all the mechanics that are meant to mimic real life, ignoring the ones that are not expected to do as such.

Comment: @derp Then that should be made explicit, since I could easily argue that since humans can run faster than realistically possible, that mechanic is not "meant to mimic real life."

Comment: @BESW I tried to do so in my edit. But an argument that the games only represent reality until level 6 because of *economics* is actually something I'd like to read (then again, I *like* economics).

Comment: I'm with BESW on that. Realism and d20 are not on a first-name basis with each other. The point of "reality ends at level 6" isn't to rigorously define anything—it merely illustrates that d20 as a whole is not a realistic simulation. Calling it a "belief" doesn't accurately represent the statements involved.

Comment: Putting this on hold - I'm not sure what problem this question is trying to solve and how it can be answered objectively.

Comment: "Why should the claim that reality ends at level 6 or below be believed?" - Do you actually mean to ask those words, or do you mean to ask something like "Why should the claim that reality ends at level 6 be believed"?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Are you seeing something I'm not? I realized one of the quotations said level 5 was peak and adjusted the question. Did I misplace a modifier or something?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The opening sentence conveys the idea that the best reality can produce is a human of level ~6. If you ask why we should believe reality ends at level 6 **or below**, that includes me suggesting reality ends at level 1 (i.e. character creation) to satisfy that yeah, it's totally reasonable to believe reality ends below level 6.

Comment: Or another way of putting it is: you introduce one idea but then ask about something related but different and maybe opposite.

Comment: @HeyICanChan - I was (slowly) working on an answer based on [this article](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/587/roleplaying-games/dd-calibrating-your-expectations-2), although I can't post it now.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Then you should recommend the question for reopening so you can answer it? Or is the problem that you'd like a more precise range?

Comment: Well it just seems the claim you should be requesting evidence for is that reality ends at level 6, and not much sooner

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't focus so much on the specific aspects of simulation. Look at the way the elements of the game interact as a whole.

For example, consider this text from [E6, the D&D variant that goes up to level 6](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?352719-necro-goodness-E6-The-Game-Inside-D-amp-D):

> To understand E6, imagine the perspective of the average medieval peasant in a d20 game. This person has the stats of a 1st-level commoner, and while they might not know their stats explicitly, they know their relation to the rest of the world. Our peasant knows that he can be killed quite easily by maurauding raiders, enemy soldiers, or even wild animals. He’s not mighty, he’s not organized, and he doesn’t have any special skills to bring to bear when danger strikes. He worries about drought and flood, and the welfare of his livestock. His extended family likely all lives within a mile of his birthplace. To him, a trip to a town ten miles off is an expedition into the unknown.
>
> Imagine you are this peasant, and you meet a trio of 6th-level adventurers. When you address the wizard, you are speaking to someone who could incinerate your home and slay all your livestock with a few words. The fighter has prevailed against a dozen orcish skirmishers and slain them all – and he could do the same again. The cleric is a man so holy that the gods themselves have granted him the power to cure the sick and heal the wounded. These are epic heroes.
>
> Now consider the powers of a CR 5 manticore. To the peasant, the appearance of this manticore near the village isn’t a nuisance: the beast can, and likely will slay you in seconds if you draw its attention. You, your livestock, and your entire family are in immediate danger of violent death. Even if you were well armed and gathered a large peasant militia, your village faces heavy losses and no guarantee of success. Against such a creature, adventurers may be your only hope. E6 recognizes that 6th level characters are mortal, while reframing the game’s perspective to create a context where those same 6th level characters are epic heroes.

In other words, level 6 characters are pretty amazing by the standard of levels 1 and 2, which is the baseline for many characters in the game world (look at the monster writeups for elves, orcs, gnomes, &c. in the monster books). **Around levels 5-6, characters pick up a bunch of lynchpin iconic abilities that really put them far above the abilities of a basic character, both quantitatively and qualitatively**: — Fireball, Cure Disease, Wind Wall, Wild Shape, Whirlwind Attack, paladin mounts, Dispel Magic, Animate Dead, &c. They can fly, they can fight huge groups of lesser foes, they can tackle forces that seem like unyielding constants to lesser characters (disease, hunger, magic).

As you move *past* levels 5-6, characters' abilities really explode. They get stuff like Raise Dead, Teleport, Plane Shift. The whole scope of their adventures changes. A lot of things that we consider basic limitations of the human condition — death itself! — aren't really obstacles to them in the same way anymore.

Comment: Although this completely answered the question for me, the current edit makes it pretty clear that the asker wants to focus on non-magical aspects of the game that parallel real-life. Might want to update to address that.

Answer (score 5):

I rather strongly doubt that there would be any truly convincing arguments to support the claim that lv. 6 is about what real humans can achieve. This is a fantasy game with its own arbitrary rules and alternate reality (of physical, biological, etc laws), where magic and dragons are real, people get healed incredibly fast, etc. You could of course strip off all the magic and all the supernatural and extraordinary stuff and then try and compare what's left (the purely physical parts of D&D, precious little stuff, half the skeleton of a magical beast that collapses in itself when stripped of all the magical muscle and bones) with the ever-changing world records of real human achievements, along with the murky and deceptive waters of statistical averages... but you'd still end up with highly debatable stuff. As in *what have you and what haven't you taken into consideration, why have you compared this to that*, etc.

I may be (quite) wrong, though.

However, you might wish to consider the arguments made by and, perhaps even more importantly, the history of a certain unofficial version of the d20 rules - namely, [***E6***](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/E6_%283.5e_Sourcebook%29). This game is, afaik, one of the most famous proponents of "*lv6 seems like a good point to stop leveling up because... because Realistic Human Limitations*" approach. It's not a bad game, mind you. And its FAQ - under "[Why is E6 designed this way](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/E6_%283.5e_Sourcebook%29/FAQ#Why_is_E6_Designed_This_Way.3F)" - sheds even more light on the possible origin of the lv6 limit:

> E6 was inspired by the article [Gandalf was a Fifth-Level Magic User](http://kuoi.org/~kamikaze/RPG/gandalf.txt) by
>   Bill Seligman. The article was published in The Dragon (which became
>   Dragon magazine) in issue #5, March 1977.